# Does CMAKE_<LANG>_LINK_EXECUTABLE supports generator expressions?

Tags: c++, cmake

I build custom cmake toolchain file with custom linker command(and it works). Like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> 
<CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> 
<LINK_FLAGS> 
<OBJECTS> 
<LINK_LIBRARIES> 
--meta /home/user/some_dir/meta.txt -o <TARGET_BASE>.exe")
```

I want to automatically extract directory from target and add relative path to it to get full path to meta. Like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> 
<CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> 
<LINK_FLAGS> 
<OBJECTS> 
<LINK_LIBRARIES> 
--meta $<TARGET_CMAKE_DIR:${TARGET}>/some_dir/meta.txt -o <TARGET_BASE>.exe")
```

In documentation I don't find anything usefull: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_EXECUTABLE.html

Is it possible to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try it? If so, did it work? Or were there errors?

Comment: Yes, I Did. input: --meta $<TARGET_CMAKE_DIR:<TARGET_BASE>>${APP_META}
Output: --meta :<TARGET_BASE>/some/dir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, generator expressions **do not work** in the "rule" variables.

The only expansion performed in such variables is `<varname>` expansions.

Possible values for `varname` seems to be hardcoded. Expansion is performed in [Source/cmRulePlaceholderExpander.cxx](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.16.2/Source/cmRulePlaceholderExpander.cxx) source, where one can find all possible names for expanded variables. (Note: many of these names are **conditionally** available for expansion).

Unfortunately, there is no `TARGET_DIR` or similar variable which is expanded.